# Changing CSS class dynamically

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have an indicator on a page which is either a red or green circle.

```
<div class="publicBm changeState" currentstate="1" statusid="56" title="This is Public"></div> <!-- green -->
<div class="privateBm changeState" currentstate="1" statusid="57" title="This is Private"></div> <!-- red -->
```

When a user clicks the circle (which is a div with class changeState as shown above) an AJAX call is made to update the database to the opposite of what the item currently is, public or private. Then it returns the opposite class.

All works perfectly but I want to change the class on the circle clicked to reflect that the update has been successful.

Here's what I'm trying - as I said, the actual database call within the php file is perfect it's just that the div is not having it's class changed.

NOTE - there can be multiple lines on each page so I can't simply give the DIV an id

```
$('.changeState').click(function() {
    var bm_id = $(this).attr('statusID');
    var current = $(this).attr('currentState');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:      '/ajax/actions/editStateBm.php?bm_id='+bm_id+'&current='+current,
        success:  
            function(data) {
                $(this).removeAttr('class').attr('class', data + ' changeState');

            }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is `this`. `this` is not the DOM element inside the ajax success callback. Instead set the context as that of the element so that `this` inside the callback now refers to the element and not jqXhr object.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:      '/ajax/actions/editStateBm.php?bm_id='+bm_id+'&current='+current,
    context: this, //<-- Here
    success:  
        function(data) {
            this.className = data + ' changeState';

        }
});
```

or use a cached context.

```
   ...
   var self = this;
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:      '/ajax/actions/editStateBm.php?bm_id='+bm_id+'&current='+current,
        success:  
            function(data) {
                self.className = data + ' changeState';

            }
    });
    ...
```

BTW what are you posting? you need to use `GET`?

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
 ....
```

Comment: Ha, how weird - i'm using GET and its getting it just fine although says type:POST

Comment: Awesome thanks, also now allowed me to make lots more changes using same theory so many thanks for that mate! Appreciate the mini lesson too.

Answer (score 1):

Use [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

```
success: function (data) {
    $(this).removeAttr('class').addClass(data + ' changeState');
}
```

and [removeProp](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/)

```
success: function (data) {
    $(this).removeProp('class').addClass(data + ' changeState');
}
```

Comment: Doesn't do anything I'm afraid

Comment: @DarrenSweeney 2 things, should that be POST or GET, and `this` doesn't represent the DOM element inside the callback. See my answer, that might work if for no other issues.

Answer (score 0):

This should be something like:

```
$(this).removeClass('class').addClass(data + ' changeState');
```